# Pop Up Pages to close once Save button is clicked

Tags: asp.net

I have 12 pop up pages on my site with a Save and Cancel button. My requirement is once the Save button is clicked on the pop page i want the server side code to execute and once its done I want the pop up to close.

Is that possible? If yes, kindly let me know how do I achieve that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end of your code the below lines of code will help to close the window.

this.Page.Response.Clear();
            this.Page.Response.Write(string.Format(CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                "window.frameElement.commonModalDialogClose(1, '{0}');", lblText.Text));
            this.Page.Response.End();

Answer (score 1):

You can put a small Javascript on each popup:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    window.close();
</script>
```

Once the page has loaded (and all the code is run) this Javascript should close the window.  Please note, different browsers will behave differently!  Some might close it, some might alert warning, others may block it completely.

As far as I know this is the only way that could close a browser window.  Either way, any number of popup windows over 0 is arguably an unfriendly user design.  10+ and you should be seriously reconsidering your user friendliness!

Answer (score 0):

What you can do:

1. Create update panel and make your Save button as trigger to it, once button is clicked it will execute code behind without closing your popup.
2. Use your ScriptManager to register statrup method (JavaScript). This method will close your popup

   ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this,this.getType(),Guid.NewGuid().ToString(),"/*your code to close popup*/",true /*this true will add script tags to your script so you don't have to write* /);

Cheers

Sorry but this SO script wont highlight code, I don't know what is the problem.